# Finding rotated orthogonal vectors without knowing lengths

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products, rotations

I have two abstract orthogonal vectors $\mid a\rangle$ and $\mid b\rangle$: $\langle a\mid b\rangle=0$, but I don't know the lengths $\mid a\mid=\sqrt{\langle a\mid a\rangle}$ and $\mid b\mid=\sqrt{\langle b\mid b\rangle}$.

I would like to find two rotated vectors

$\mid a'\rangle=c_1\mid a\rangle+c_2\mid b\rangle$

$\mid b'\rangle=c_3\mid a\rangle+c_3\mid b\rangle$

that are still orthogonal, in terms of the coefficients $c_i$. Is this possible without knowing the lengths?

If they were of unit length I could use

$\mid a'\rangle=\cos\theta\mid a\rangle+\sin\theta\mid b\rangle$

$\mid b'\rangle=-\sin\theta\mid a\rangle+\cos\theta\mid b\rangle$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \langle a'\mid b' \rangle=0$

And if I knew their lengths I could use

$\mid a'\rangle=\cos\theta\mid a\rangle+\frac{\mid a\mid}{\mid b\mid}\sin\theta\mid b\rangle$

$\mid b'\rangle=-\frac{\mid b\mid}{\mid a\mid}\sin\theta\mid a\rangle+\cos\theta\mid b\rangle$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \Longrightarrow \langle a'\mid b' \rangle=0$

But what about my case?

Note: I don't actually need the general rotation, just some rotated still orthogonal set; ideally rotated $90^{\circ}$.

EDIT: I realised that I can set up the equations for $c_i$, and I get

$c_1^*c_3\mid a\mid^2+c_2^*c_4\mid b\mid^2=0$

which I can't solve; does that mean that what I need is impossible or could there still be some trick?

Comment: But it's not obvious from this: $\langle a'\mid b'\rangle=-\sin\theta\cos\theta\langle a\mid a\rangle+\cos\theta\sin\theta\langle b\mid b\rangle$

Comment: @user251257 the described transformation is not a rotation unless $a$ and $b$ happen to be of the same length

Comment: I am confused. the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} c & s \\ -s & c \end{pmatrix}$ is unitary, where $c$ is the cosine and $s$ is the sine. it is probably a reflection, not a rotation. I can't remember the proper ordering

Comment: That's right. However, the transformation described here only has that matrix with respect to the basis $\{a,b\}$.  Since this is not an *orthonormal* basis, we can't guarantee that the transformation is unitary.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ah I see. thx.

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary angle $\theta$, we have
$$
\langle a'\mid b'\rangle=\\
-\sin\theta\cos\theta\langle a\mid a\rangle+\cos\theta\sin\theta\langle b\mid b\rangle = \\
\cos \theta \sin \theta (\langle a\mid a\rangle - \langle b\mid b\rangle) =\\
\frac 12 \sin (2 \theta) (\langle a\mid a\rangle - \langle b\mid b\rangle)
$$
So, in order to have $\langle a'\mid b'\rangle = 0$, we must either have $\langle a\mid a\rangle = \langle b\mid b\rangle$, or $\sin (2 \theta) = 0$.

Comment: In other words, not knowing their lengths the only thing I can do is interchange the two vectors and/or change their overall signs?

Comment: Yes.  Or, if you know that the two lengths are different, then that's still all you can do.

Comment: But I can picture two orthogonal spatial vectors with unequal length being rotated and staying orthogonal? And your point doesn't seem to just point out it's impossible to find the coefficients but that they don't exist (unless I'm mistaken)?

Comment: If you were actually *rotating* the vectors, then they would stay orthogonal.  However, the transformation that you describe is not a rotation in the usual sense.  In particular, if you were to trace the "tip" of $a'$ as you change $\theta$, the result would be an ellipse as opposed to a circle (unless $a$ and $b$ happen to have the same length).

Comment: And you're right.  My point is that either *every* $\theta$ works (when $|a| = |b|$), or the only values that work are the multiples of $90^\circ$.

Comment: Ok, so I should probably rephrase the question (maybe I'll edit): are there _any_ $c_i$ that will give me two new (not just different overall sign) vectors that are orthogonal? Seems to me there must be, but maybe finding them is hard?

Comment: If we don't want any of the trivial solutions (that is, the solutions where some $c_i$ is zero), then we must have
$$
\frac{c_1^*c_3}{c_2^*c_4} = -\frac{|b|^2}{|a|^2}
$$
presumably, however, doing anything with this assumes knowledge of $|b|$ and $|a|$.

Comment: Of course, if the $c_i$ are not determined to by the sine or cosine of some angle, then I wonder in what sense this is at all a "rotation".